# How can I recover a staged changes from a deleted git worktree?

Tags: git, git-worktree

I accidentally deleted a worktree, with staged, but uncommitted changes!
But `git worktree list` still shows the worktree (i.e., it hasn't been pruned)

Say,

```
/home/me/worktreeexample            0d4f25f [fix/something]
/home/me/                           0fd8c7e [master]
```

But because I just ran `rm -rf worktreeexample/` there is nothing there
    $ ls worktreeexample/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new file in `worktreeexample` telling `git` where to look. The format is based on the contents of `.git/worktrees`.

So, for the example above, this will work:

```
echo "gitdir: /home/me/.git/worktrees/worktreeexample" > worktreeexample/.git
```

Then running `git status` in `worktreeexample/` will show all your deleted files, and hopefully also your work in progress to be committed. Run

```
cd worktreeexample
git checkout -- .
```

which will leave only the staged changes.

**Note** if you have *unstaged* changes and you destroyed the working directory, you are out of luck.

Comment: Yes, luckily the index for the extra work-tree is stored in the "main" git repository's `.git` directory rather than in the additional work-tree, so you can recover everything from that (still-existing) index file. If you've blown away the index file as well, you are not *quite* out of luck yet: you can run `git fsck --lost-found` and look at all the recovered files. The *names* of the files will be lost (replaced with blob hash IDs), and sorting out the mess can be painful. As you note, *unstaged* changes are just gone (unless your OS does backups/snapshots, e.g., MacOS Time Machine).